# Could there be remnants or hidden places with javascript after using PDFBox's flatten method? We can assume that there is no XFA involved

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm already flattening the PDF with the PDFBox's method and removing any XFA related but are there any other possible areas/ways where javascript could remain?

I've looked into https://lists.apache.org/thread/bj5v8zc87fv5ljwm37cdpl4o7bp5k5j6 but I'm not sure if the flatten method is performing the same operations since the answer is quite dated.

Comment: That mailing list answer appears to focus on JavaScript in form fields. But there still may be more JavaScript in the page actions and at document level. Simply take the PDF spec and look for JavaScript there...

Comment: There are [some approaches](https://github.com/Lonzak/PdfJavascriptStripper) to this however using itext/openPDF.

Comment: @mkl Would you have an example of something like that? I've been searching for something that uses PDFBox and traverses through the document but most of them seem to be just focusing on Acroform.

Comment: @lonzak  Thanks for that reference. But it seems to be using iText. I'm primarily using PDFBox.

Comment: Even though Lonzak's `PdfJavascriptStripper` is based on iText, you can adopt ideas from it. Essentially it traverses all objects in a PDF and in dictionaries with a **JS** entry sets the value of that entry to an empty string. Additionally it removes the **JavaScript** names tree. And this is what you have to do with PDFBox, too. And no, I don't have an example at hand.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - I thought that it is clear when I had written my answer (even pointed out that it is iText based)